# Repeating a while loop within a while loop

Tags: matlab

```
x = [];
i = 0;
p = 0;
count = 0;
hold on
while 1

if count == 100
    break;
end

while 1
n = rand(1); 
if i > 499
break;
end

if n > 0.5
p = p+1;
end
if n < 0.5
p = p-1;
end
if n==1
p = p;
end
i = i+1;
x(i) = p;
end

X = abs(x);
Y = 1:length(X);

ps = csapi(X,Y);

plot(X,Y,'o');
fnplt(ps)

count = count +1;
end
hold off
grid on
title('Random Walk Distances')
xlabel('Distance from the Origin')
ylabel('Each Iteration of the Experiment')
```

I’d like to repeat the process in my initial while loop to have multiple curves on one plot, and I would also like to find a mean curve of the curves that I plot, any idea on how to do this?

Comment: First, select your code in Matlab and press `ctrl+i`, that will indent the code and make it readable. Second, what the problem with the results, according to your goals?

Comment: Ah, I think I've got it. If you want all the curves in the same figure, you have to remove the first three lines into the first while loop, immediately after the `while`. But 100 lines with 500 dots for each is just a mass on one figure, you better re-think about how you want to show your results

Answer (score 1):

This code gives you all the plots in one figure. But, if you do this, it looks more like a painting than like an overview of curves. I also cleaned up your code a bit. It's useless to use a while-loop if you know how many times your loop needs to run and if there are no other triggers to break the loop. So you can change them to a for-loop.

```
close all;
p = 0;
hold on
for count = 0:99

    x = cell(1,1);

    for i = 1:499

        n = rand(1); 

        if n > 0.5
            p = p+1;
        end

        if n < 0.5
            p = p-1;
        end

        if n==1
            p = p;
        end

        x{i} = p;
    end

    x = cell2mat(x);
    X = abs(x);
    Y = 1:length(X);

    ps = csapi(X,Y);

    plot(X,Y,'o');
    fnplt(ps)    

end

hold off
grid on
title('Random Walk Distances')
xlabel('Distance from the Origin')
ylabel('Each Iteration of the Experiment')
```

[image]